# gazebo.hh not found

Tags: ros, rosws, gazebo-plugin, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm currently trying to do this tutorial
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/tutorials/plugins/simple_world

but at when I compile the code,
'cmake' works fine but
'make' produces the following error

```
/home/u0905937/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/hello_world.cc:1:21: fatal error: gazebo.hh: No such file or directory
```

I did a locate and found gazebo.hh in

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/include/gazebo-1.0.2/gazebo/gazebo.hh
```

Does the problem has anything to do with my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or ROS_WORKSPACE?
I've tried adding the above location to my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH but to no avail. My ROS_WORKSPACE is /home/u0905937/fuerte_workspace if that is any help.

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04

EDIT: Thanks Kai, I've tried using the rosmake method and at least it could partially build the package.

But I still face the problem of the computer not being able to find gazebo.hh. I've tried copying gazebo.hh into /usr/include/ but it came up with a new error of not being able to find the next header which is gazebo_core.hh. So I copy and pasted it again which brought up another new error of not being able to find the next header the previous one referred to. There's got to be an easier way right?

By the way, my system is downgraded to ubuntu 11.10.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42706/gazebo.hh-not-found/) by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS, you can give [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/GazeboPluginIntro) a try.

Alternatively, give the following prefix to your cmake command:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=`rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/lib/pkgconfig cmake ..
```

and things should build correctly.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on 2012-09-10**:
Okay thanks. It tried on ubuntu 12.04 and your tutorial works perfectly fine.

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2015-12-05**:
Where in CMakelists.txt, I should I add it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

when using gazebo with ROS you have to do some different steps when building your plugin.

1. add the dependency gazebo_plugins to the manifest.xml of your package

   (I also added gazebo as dependency, but I think you don't need it to compile the plugin)
2. use rosmake to build the plugin
   There should be a tutorial for building packages somewhere on ros.org in case you don't know how. In short:
   add "rosbuild_add_library(libname src/sourcefile.cpp)" to the CMakeList.txt and run rosmake.

I think rosmake uses it's own cmake version or settings that adds the directories of dependent packages to the compiler flags. You could add additional include directories to your cmake file, but that's not the "ros way".

---

Originally posted by [Kai Bublitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1332/kai-bublitz/) with karma: 357 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2